# three.js dual viewports only one displays

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have tried to clone Lee Stemkoski's excellent example of dual viewports at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Dual.html.

It runs fine when accessed from its location on github on my local PC Windows 7 using Firefox 23.0.1.
But when I copy the source and try to run it from my local drive it will only show the second viewport to be rendered.
If I comment out the code for the second viewport rendering then it will show the first viewport OK.

It may be a version problem.  I would have gotten the code from GitHub but it doesnt seem to be there.
I obtained the source by doing "save as complete web page" from Firefox.
To assist debugging I then minimized the javascript by progressively cutting out inessentials like stats, controls, information button.

I have run out of ideas and wonder if anyone can see what the problem is .
The last 11 lines of the underneath code block are where the action is.

Cheers.

=========================================================================================================================

```
<!doctype html> // based on Three.js "tutorials by example" Author: Lee Stemkoski Date: June 2012 (three.js v49)
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <title> LIGER05 -- Three.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<style>
    body 
    {
        font-family: Monospace;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #ccccff;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style> </head>
<body>
<!-- <div id="message"></div>-->
<script src="js/Three.js"></script>
<script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="js/Stats.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.KeyboardState.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.FullScreen.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>
<div id="ThreeJScontainer" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div><!-- Pre-defined Container for rendered can
<script>  // based on Three.js "tutorials by example" Author: Lee Stemkoski Date: June 2012 (three.js v49) -->
var container, scene, camera, camera2, renderer;
init();
animate();
// FUNCTIONS //
function init() {
scene = new THREE.Scene();
// CAMERA //
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth , SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;  
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = (0.5*SCREEN_WIDTH) / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
camera  = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
scene.add(camera);
scene.add(camera2);
camera.position.set(0,0,200);
camera2.position.set(0,250,0);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
camera2.lookAt(scene.position);     
// RENDERER NEW
if ( Detector.webgl )
    {renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );}//alert("WebGL Renderer");         }
else
    {renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();}//alert("Canvas Renderer");         }
renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
//...Either create a div element to contain the renderer        ==> container = document.createElement( 'div' );
container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJScontainer' ); //...OR reference predefined container in the html
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
//Hmmmm   THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0,250,0);
    scene.add(light);
    //var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
    // scene.add(ambientLight);
var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50, 32, 16 ); 
    // use a "lambert" material rather than "basic" for realistic lighting.//(don't forget to add >= 1 light!)
    var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0x8888ff} ); 
    var sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    sphere1.position.set(-60, 0, 50);
    scene.add(sphere1);  
    var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    sphere2.position.set(0, 0, -50);
    scene.add(sphere2);         
    var sphere3 = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    sphere3.position.set(60, 0, 50);
    scene.add(sphere3);                 
    }
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
render();       
update();   }
function update() {
// delta = change in time since last call (in seconds)
var delta = clock.getDelta(); }
function render(){  
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
camera.aspect = (0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH) / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
camera2.aspect = (0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH) / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
var mar = 100
var panelX1min = mar
var panelWidth = Math.floor(0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH) - (2* mar)
var panelX2min = mar + panelWidth + mar + mar
var panelYmin = mar
var panelHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT - (2*mar)
//...LEFT SIDE 
renderer.setViewport( panelX1min, panelYmin, panelWidth , panelHeight  );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
//...RIGHT SIDE

    // ***** if you comment out the next two lines then the left side viewport will be shown *****

renderer.setViewport( panelX2min, panelYmin, panelWidth, panelHeight ); 
renderer.render( scene, camera2 );
}
</script></body></html>
=========================================================================================================================
=========================================================================================================================
```

Comment: well, any console errors?

Comment: @GuyGood  No, no console errors, just a report giving version of webgl renderer.

Comment: Aha. Think I found it.  Need to put statement: renderer.autoClear = false;  at the end of the Init function.  Nothing to do with CSS. @GuyGood Thanks for looking at it, sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needed the following statement (in the javascript init function) 
to prevent renderer clearing its buffer after rendering the first viewport:-

```
    renderer.autoClear = false
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer! It helped me out with the same problem as well.